# Github API organisation access using OAuth app

Tags: github, google-apps-script, github-api

I'm building a Google Spreadsheet app where Google app script will commit the generated files into a git repository. Access is using an OAuth app, client id and secret.

Committing files to repo that I own works fine, but when I try to commit and push files to a repository I created under an organisation, it seems like the repo isn't there.

> Error: {"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/git#create-a-blob"}

Looking at both, the only difference between them is the URL used to access the API.

The one that works: `https://api.github.com/repos/[my username]/[repo name]/git/blobs`

Not working: `https://api.github.com/repos/[org name]/[repo name]/git/blobs`

Is there a separate API for dealing with organisation repo? I even created a public repo to test and it wouldnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

The OAuth app access was denied as it was created with my account. Create the OAuth app with the organisation account instead.